# Estimating Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process drift

Tags: stochastic-processes, mean-reversion, ornstein-uhlenbeck

What is the easiest way to obtain a drift parameter of O-U process given I have $\mu$?

Is it ok to linearize the O-U process like so:

$P_{t} = \mu + \phi(P_{t-1}-\mu)+\xi_t$

Form vectors from historic data:

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
\ P_0-\mu \\ 
\ P_1-\mu \\
\ \dots \\
\ P_T-1-\mu \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
b = \begin{bmatrix}
\ \mu \\ 
\ \mu \\
\ \dots \\
\ \dots \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
Y = \begin{bmatrix}
\ P_1 \\ 
\ P_2 \\
\ \dots \\
\ P_T \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

And solve $\phi$ with OLS?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, using a rolling AR-1 and μ

Comment: Hi @Anthony Suherli, thanks for your answer. Would you be willing to extend your answer a little bit so that it can be helpful for future readers as well? That'd be great!

Comment: dp(t) = α(t) + k (μ- p(t)) dt + σ dW(t), k>0

where lim α(t) -> inf = μ, and dW(t) at time t becomes 0 because we dont use p(t-1)

now dp(t) = α(t) + k (μ- p(t)) dt

we can estimate using an ar1 using a window (say 60 past observations), and kind of simulate a model with μ- p(t) as input. α(t) should average to μ

Now you will get an estimate of k from every observation, you can average them or do anything that best suite your needs